# ColumnTransformer fails with CountVectorizer in a pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to transform text using `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer` within pipelines combined with `ColumnTransformer`. However, the pipeline returns an incorrect array. Why is my pipeline with `ColumnTransformer` giving me a wrong 1-by-1 array for `CountVectorize`-d text?

I realize I could simply use a single pipeline with `CountVectorizer`, and omit `ColumnTransformer`. However, later I will need to add numeric columns, making `ColumnTransformer` necessary. I tried this originally, found errors, and isolated the issue to the problem described above.

I've tried inputting `X` as a series instead of a dataframe, but got another error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'text_feat':['This is my first sentence.','This is my second.'], 
                          'numeric_feat':[1,2], 
                          'target':[3,4]})
X = data.loc[:,['text_feat', 'numeric_feat']]
y = data.loc[:,'target']

# first pipeline 
text_features = ['text_feat']
text_transformer = Pipeline(
        steps = [('vec', CountVectorizer())])

# wrap in ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[('text', text_transformer, text_features)])

# second pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor)])

# single pipeline works as expected
X_expected = text_transformer.fit_transform(X['text_feat'])

# but this fails
X_test = pipeline.fit_transform(X)

print('Expected:')
print(X_expected.toarray())
print('Got:')
print(X_test)
```

I expected the 2-by-6 array `array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])` (document-term matrix from CountVectorizer). Instead, I got this: `array([[1]])`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `make_column_transformer` and do something like the following. remainder are the remaining features on which you can apply other transformations. By default, remainder is set to 'drop' which means that the remaining features without any transformations will be dropped.:

```
preprocess = make_column_transformer((CountVectorizer(), 'text_feat'), 
                                     remainder='passthrough')
make_pipeline(preprocess).fit_transform(X)
```

More info [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html)

The following blog goes into more details:
https://jorisvandenbossche.github.io/blog/2018/05/28/scikit-learn-columntransformer/

A few tips on your code:
While transforming features, you do not need to (read: shouldn't)  pass y (i.e. the target).
The issue in your code is because you are passing the list of text features instead of name the column. If you change your code slightly, you should get the same results.

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[('text', text_transformer, 'text_feat')])
```

Comment: I made the fix (list-of-text features to just the string). I think that's all I needed. Now, would there be any additional benefit to switching to `make_column_transformer`?

Comment: ColumnTransformer is much more customizable and hence, requires more parameters. For example, naming your transformer is mandatory. But, it comes with additional benefits such as transformer_weights etc. make_column_transformer is a bit more concise. The same argument holds for the differences between make_pipeline and Pipeline objects. Minus the transformer_weights argument since it is not applicable to Pipeline objects.

Comment: I also ran into this issue. Passing the text feature as `str` instead of `list` solved the issue for me.

Comment: @blacksite what if we have more than one text feature? Any idea to solve it?

Comment: @demirbilek did you end up finding an answer to this ? COuntVectorizer on several text features?

Answer (score 0):

```
# wrap in ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('text', CountVectorizer(),'text_feat')])

# second pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor)])

X_test = pipeline.fit_transform(X)
```

This works and seems the simplest for me.