# ColumnTransformer fails with CountVectorizer/HashingVectorizer in a pipeline (multiple textfeatures)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Similar to this problem ([ColumnTransformer fails with CountVectorizer in a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772181/columntransformer-fails-with-countvectorizer-in-a-pipeline)) I want to apply `CountVectorizer/HashingVectorizer` on a column with Text-features using the `ColumnTransformer` in a pipeline. But I do not have only one text-feature, but multiple. If I pass a single feature (not as list, like suggested in the solution to the other question) it works fine, how do I do it for multiple?

```python
numeric_features = ['x0', 'x1', 'y0', 'y1']
categorical_features = []
text_features = ['text_feature', 'another_text_feature']

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler())])
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder())])
text_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('hashing', HashingVectorizer())])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_features), 
    ('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ('text', text_transformer, text_features)
])
    
steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
         ('clf', SGDClassifier())]
    
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
    
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a separate transformer for each text feature.

```py
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_features), 
    ('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ('text', text_transformer, 'text_feature'),
    ('more_text', text_transformer, 'another_text_feature'),
])
```

(The transformers get cloned during fitting, so you'll have two separate copies of `text_transformer` and everything is fine.  If it worries you to specify the same transformer twice like this, you could always copy/clone it manually before specifying the `ColumnTransformer`.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Ben! Thought of that shortly after, and works fine. To keep my pipeline parametrized I create the `transformers` list from my chosen text features by `[other_transformers] + [(tf, text_transformer, tf) for tf in text_features]`