# Logistic regression with two text features

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I can only find ways to implement logistic regression with just one text feature (i.e. spam detection), where TFIDF would be used. But as Feature_A and Feature_B are the features to predict the label I'd like to know which method to use when working with two text features as in my (limited) knowledge using TFIDF only works with one text feature. I'll be using Python and SciKit-learn. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Example of the kind of dataset I'll be working with:

| Feature_A | Feature_B | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | consectetur adipiscing elit | 0 |
| Proin venenatis | est sit amet rhoncus efficitur | 1 |
| non bibendum massa nulla nec nulla | Quisque sit amet suscipit ligula | 1 |
| Quisque aliquet lacus non nibh elementum faucibus | posuere, justo eget malesuada porta | 0 |
| justo sem vestibulum felis | ac facilisis ante nulla a justo | 1 |

Comment: You can transform each column one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If the two texts are related in a way you want reflected in the tfidf, consider concatenating them.

Otherwise, you can just encode them separately and hstack the results; that can be done with a `ColumnTransformer`, see [ColumnTransformer fails with CountVectorizer/HashingVectorizer in a pipeline (multiple textfeatures)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68381331/10495893).